# How to find slope of LinearRegression using sklearn on python?

Tags: python, linear-regression

I'm newbie in python and I would like to find slope and intercept using sklearn package. Below is my code.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

def findLinearRegression():
    x = [1,2,3,4,5]
    y = [5,7,12,9,15]
    lrm = LinearRegression()

    lrm.fit(x,y)
    m = lrm.coef_
    c = lrm.intercept_
    print(m)
    print(c)
```

I got an error ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead. Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to reshape the `x` and `y` series to a 2D array.

Replace the code where you declare `x` and `y` with the below code and the function would work the way intended.

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array([5,7,12,9,15]).reshape(-1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

x should be a column vector

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]).reshape(-1,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reshape your inputs. Simply replace

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

by

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]).reshape(-1, 1)
```